# live Boot any linux distro to console

Tags: linux, boot, x11, ethtool, live-cd

Is there any .iso linux image distro that boots into console and not into x?

I just want to run some simple linux commands like ethtool

alternatively, I would like any boot cd that let me test the physical connection of a NIC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Knoppix will do it with the knoppix-txt kernel boot label.  See [Knoppix Cheat Codes](http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Cheat_Codes).

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux Live Distributions provide an option to boot into text mode.

[Here](http://grml.org/) is a good option for sysadmins.